# Degrees of Fundamental Invariants of Coxeter Groups $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, coxeter-groups

I think I misunderstood something simple but not sure what.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_element,

> The invariants of the Coxeter group acting on polynomials form a polynomial algebra whose generators are the fundamental invariants; their degrees are given in the table above

The Coxeter group $A_{n}$ is a group generated by reflections in the hyperplans defined by $e_{i} - e_{i+1} \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ where $\{e_i\}$ is a orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. So $A_{n}$ permutes coordinates of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and it is in fact isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_{n+1}$. Therefore the $A_{n}$-invariant polynomials of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dotsc,X_{n+1}]$ are elementary symmetric polynomials
\begin{equation}
Y_1 = X_1X_2\dotsm X_{n+1}, \qquad \dotsc \qquad Y_{n+1} = X_1 + X_2 + \dotsb + X_{n+1}.
\end{equation}
So the degrees of fundamental invariants should be $n+1,n,\dotsc,2,1$ but the same wikipedia page (and every other sources I checked) will say these degrees are $n+1,n,\dotsc,2$. Apparently we will always restrict the action of $A_n$ to the subspace $X_1 + \dotsb + X_{n+1} = 0$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and ignore $Y_{n+1}$ but why is that? Is $Y_{n+1}$ not a valid invariant polynomial of $A_n$?

Comment: $Y_1$ is a product of $X_i$ but $Y_{n+1}$ is a sum of $X_i$. I added $X_2$ maybe that will make the question more readable.

Comment: Maybe I guess that the degree of $0$ is $0$. This is an intresting quesion.

Answer (score 4):

The degrees of the fundamental invariants are not invariants of the Coxeter group but rather depend upon the particular representation. More specifically, the *degrees* are defined for any finite subgroup $G \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(V)$ with the property that the invariant subalgebra $\mathrm{Sym}(V^*)^G$ is a polynomial ring: these are the degrees of a system of homogeneous generators. If the vector space $V$ is defined over a field of characteristic $0$, the groups with this property are precisely the *reflection groups*; if the field is the real numbers then each reflection group is isomorphic to a finite Coxeter group and each finite Coxeter group occurs in this way.

The point for you is that the embedding $G \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(V)$ must be specified before you can make sense of the invariants. For the symmetric group $S_n=W(A_{n-1})$, it is customary to refer to its *permutation* and its *reflection* representation, of dimension $n$ and $n-1$, respectively. Each comes with its own set of degrees.